# How to update a column after select it?

Tags: mysql

I need to update the 'views' column of a table after selecting it. How can I do it?

```
id|name|views|
--|----|-----|
 1|  a |  0  |
 2|  a |  0  |
 3|  b |  0  |
```

Something like:

```
SELECT name 
FROM table 
WHERE name LIKE 'a' "
```

and increment by 1 it views column right after.

Comment: What you mean after a `SELECT`? if you want update you use `UPDATE` statement

Comment: Tell us your requirement to understand it

Comment: You need to use an `update` sql statement.

Comment: just do UPDATE table SET views = 'some_value' WHERE id = 'id of item to update';

Comment: Google 'mysql update query', then visit any of the results; problem solved!

Comment: `LIKE ` without any wildcard `%` is the same as `=` operator

Comment: I want to select 'a' and update its 'views' on the same query. So i know, 'a' was selected n times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL, or SQL in general really, does not support updating data in a select statement. However, such behavior could be emulated with a stored procedure that contains both the select and update statements; returning the select's results.